# Overflow properties working differently on a div inside and outside a CSS grid

Tags: css, overflow, css-grid, bootstrap-grid

I have the following structure, which I will call 'list of files' (using Bootstrap 4):

```css
.file-component {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.file-component .file-name {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="file-component">
      <p class="file-name">Some long file name inside the grid that really does not fit inside the available space</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="file-component">
      <p class="file-name">Some long file name inside the grid that really does not fit inside the available space</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="file-component">
      <p class="file-name">Some long file name inside the grid that really does not fit inside the available space</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="file-component">
      <p class="file-name">Some long file name inside the grid that really does not fit inside the available space</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Each file component in this 'list of files' is composed of a `p` tag inside a `div`<sup>1</sup>. To make things responsive, the `div` should have a length that is determined by the `bootstrap grid` classes `col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4`, depending on the size of the screen. At certain breakpoints, the items in the `div`s occupy a different number of columns, until they are eventually stacked on top of each other. At all times, the `p` tag should fit inside the `div` width, cutting off any text that falls outside the div.

For example, if the text is short (or the `div` is wide enough), it is all visible:

[image: Short name]

But, if it is long (or the `div` is narrow), we get:

[image: Long name]

Now, this works pretty well as it is. For a wide screen:

[image: Wide screen]

And for a really narrow screen:

[image: Narrow screen]

The problem appears when I try to put all this inside a CSS grid layout:

```css
.file-component {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.file-component .file-name {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.grid-container-component .grid-central-container {
  grid-area: cnt;
  border-left: solid 2px;
  border-right: solid 2px;
}

/* Medium sized screens (900px < width < 1400px) */
.grid-container-component {
  display: grid;
  border: solid 2px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 7fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "lt cnt rt";
  margin-top: 30px;
}

/* Wide screens (> 1400px wide) */
@media (min-width: 1400px) {
  .grid-container-component {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "lt cnt rt";
  }
}

/* Small Screens (< 900px wide) */
@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .grid-container-component {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "cnt";
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="grid-container-component">
  <div class="grid-central-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="file-component">
          <p class="file-name">Some long file name inside the grid that really does not fit inside the available space</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="file-component">
          <p class="file-name">Some long file name inside the grid that really does not fit inside the available space</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="file-component">
          <p class="file-name">Some long file name inside the grid that really does not fit inside the available space</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="file-component">
          <p class="file-name">Some long file name inside the grid that really does not fit inside the available space</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the screen is wide, all works as expected. For example (CSS grid is shown in black):

[image: Large screen CSS grid]

However, for very narrow screens, it seem the `p` tag does not let the `div.file-component` become shorter than the text it contains. Therefore, the `div.file-component` overflows on the right of the grid and a horizontal scroll bar appears on the bottom:

[image: Overflow]

[image: Overflow 2]

Any idea why this could be happening?? Any alternative ways of doing this are welcome too!

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>In reality there are more things inside this div, but for the simple example this is good enough.</sub>

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks for your comment and for helping me improve my questions. I've added the Stack Snippets and reduced the example a bit more.